# How can I perform a sanity check to confirm data is consistent after a repair?

Tags: cassandra

How can i check for data sanity after performing nodetool repair on cassandra to validate that data is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify that data is consistent, run a repair.

I know that seems to be a circular argument but there is no other way to validate that replicas are in sync without performing a repair.

During a repair, Cassandra performs a Merkle tree comparison where it does a digest check of each leaf and compares it to the corresponding leaves of the replicas to validate inconsistencies and repairs them if the digests don't match.

If you have just run a repair, it sounds like you don't trust that it was successful. If so, what evidence do you have that it didn't work? If you update your original question with the evidence, I would be happy to review it and update my answer. Cheers!

Comment: Well what i actually want is an evidence itself that data is in reality consistent after nodetool repair.

Comment: Also, is there an option to see the consistency without running the repair?

Comment: We want to know about inconsistencies before running repair.

Comment: As I explained, the Merkle tree calculation performed by repairs is what determines whether there is inconsistency or not. At the end of the day, dropped mutations (missed writes) is the inconsistency which happens because your nodes cannot keep up with writes. Cheers!

Comment: can i use nodetool cfastats to determine inconsistencies before calling nodetool repair?

Comment: No, it's not as I've explained in my last comment. Cheers!